# Divide column into two using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working with very basic HTML and CSS I want to divide a column into two using HTML and CSS my HTML snippet is as follows.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML div Tag</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="left1">
        <p>This is discribed in the style sheet as div.left1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="left2">
        <p>This is discribed in the style sheet as div.left2.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>This is discribed in the style sheet as div.right.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS snippet.

```
div.left1 {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    width: 68%;
    height:50%; 
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    float: left;
}
div.left2 {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    width: 68%;
    height:50%; 
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    float: left;
}
div.right {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    width: 20%;
    height:100%;  
    padding: 0 5% 0 0;
    float: right;
}
```

I am expecting output as follows.Left content divided into two and the right content is arranged in the bottom of the page. But on the output screen, the left column is coming after the right column how to solve this?

I am expecting output in at this way.

[image]

Comment: can you post an image of how you want the output?

Comment: You need at least 10 reputation to post an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, but I'm not sure

### css

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
div.left1 {
  background-color:#eeeeee;
  width: 68%;
  height:50%; 
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  float: left
}
div.left2 {
  background-color:#eeeeee;
  width: 68%;
  height:50%; 
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  float: left
}
div.right {
 background-color:#eeeeee;
 width: 20%;
 height:100%;  
 padding: 0 5% 0 0;
 float: right;
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

### html

```
<div class="left1">
  <p>This is discribed in the style sheet as div.left1.</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <p>This is discribed in the style sheet as div.right.</p>
</div>
<div class="left2">
  <p>This is discribed in the style sheet as div.left2.</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5anxsa1m/

Your code was correct, you just had to change the position of the `.right` div in the Html

Comment: If i am changing >width: 30%; In div.right the middle column is pushing both columns up and down how to avoid this?.

Comment: you would need to adjust the padding to 2% or use box-sizing:border-box;

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure, if I get you right, but here's my suggestion.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.left1 {
background-color:#eeeeee;
width: 68vw;
height:50vh; 
padding: 0 0 0 0;
float: left
}
div.left2 {
background-color:#dddddd;
width: 68vw;
height:50vh; 
padding: 0 0 0 0;
float: left
}
div.right {
background-color:#cccccc;
width: 32vw;
height:100vh;  
padding: 0 0 0 0;
float: right
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML div Tag</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="left1">
<p>This is discribed in the style sheet as div.left1.</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
<p>This is discribed in the style sheet as div.right.</p>
</div>
  <div class="left2">
<p>This is discribed in the style sheet as div.left2.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If i am changing >width: 30%; In div.right the middle column is pushing both columns up and down how to avoid this?

Comment: If you delete the padding (5%), you can go up to 32vw/% width, because `100-68=32`. At that point (see my updated snippet), the complete viewport is used, no more space left to cover.